# Fastest Way to Wrap C++ Object in Native NodeJS Addon

Tags: javascript, c++, node.js, node-gyp

As the title says, I am looking for the fastest way to wrap a native C++ object into a v8::Object. A sample of the code I currently have looks like:

```
Nan::Persistent<v8::Function> Vector3::constructor;

void Vector3::Initialise() // Static, Called once.
{
    v8::Local<v8::FunctionTemplate> objectTemplate = Nan::New<v8::FunctionTemplate>();

    objectTemplate->SetClassName(Nan::New("Vector3").ToLocalChecked());
    objectTemplate->InstanceTemplate()->SetInternalFieldCount(1);

    constructor.Reset(objectTemplate->GetFunction());
}

v8::Local<v8::Object> Vector3::WrapObject(double* components) // Static
{
    v8::Local<v8::Function> constructorFunction = Nan::New(Vector3::constructor);
    v8::Local<v8::Object> localObject = Nan::NewInstance(constructorFunction).ToLocalChecked();

    Nan::Set(localObject, Nan::New("X").ToLocalChecked(), Nan::New<v8::Number>(components[0]));
    Nan::Set(localObject, Nan::New("Y").ToLocalChecked(), Nan::New<v8::Number>(components[1]));
    Nan::Set(localObject, Nan::New("Z").ToLocalChecked(), Nan::New<v8::Number>(components[2]));

    return localObject;
}
```

The full code is a bit more complex as each vector is a property of some wrapped entity class.

From reading the many online tutorials and posts it seems like this is one of the most common ways to wrap an object, however, is there any faster way?

Profiling the code highlights Nan::Set as a major bottleneck. In particular, it seems Set internally calls two v8 methods:

```
v8::internal::Object::SetProperty
```

and

```
v8::internal::LookupIterator::PropertyOrElement
```

with each method taking up about 50% of the total Set function.

So my thoughts are:

1. Is there anyway to bypass the lookup function and call SetProperty directly?
   Surely the lookup step is redundant here as I know ahead of time that I am setting a property and not an element.
2. Is there perhaps a way to define the properties on the object template in the Initialise method and then just set them using some integer index (while still retaining them as named properties and not elements) rather than the string name so the lookup is faster?
3. Is there any way to set multiple properties on an object at the same time?
4. Is there a better method entirely?

Comment: you could store your data in the c++ object instance which you then bind to the javascript object in the internal field. Then implement javascript properties that get the values directly.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. While I didn't end up doing this exactly it gave me the idea to instead turn my c++ object into JSON, and then just pass the JSON string instead. It went from taking ~2s to ~0.2s!